# Change Android Fragment without creating new one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I switch my fragment with the following (and working!) code:

```
Fragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But always when I call this code (and it's often because it's in a navigation bar), the `onCreateView` function is called.

I could image that it's because of the `new DashboardFragment();`, but I do not know what I could change.

Is it possible to create the Fragment just one time and access to it the next times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find a previously added `Fragment` by using the `FragmentManager`
When you first add your `Fragment` give it a tag so you can retrieve it later. This is done like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment, "my_fragment_tag");
```

Then whenever you wanna get your `fragment` just use the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
DashboardFragment dashboard = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("my_fragment_tag");
if(dashboard) {
    //Do whatever you want with the fragment
} else {

    dashboard = new DashboardFragment();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you try, the `onCreateView` method always will be called after replace your `Fragment`, This method is automatic called because It’s part of the [lifecycle’s Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)

That said, you can hold the `Fragment` variables values saving a static instance and calling it through an static initializer method:

```
private static SameInstanceFragment sameInstanceFragment;

public static SameInstanceFragment getInstance() {
    sameInstanceFragment = sameInstanceFragment == null ? new SameInstanceFragment() : sameInstanceFragment;
    return sameInstanceFragment;
}
```

With the next example you will see how the `Fragment` instantiated every time can’t hold its values, while the one that has been saved as a unique instance can do it:

//SameInstanceFragment

```
public class SameInstanceFragment extends Fragment {

private static SameInstanceFragment sameInstanceFragment;
private int mCounter;

public static SameInstanceFragment getInstance() {
    sameInstanceFragment = sameInstanceFragment == null ? new SameInstanceFragment() : sameInstanceFragment;
    return sameInstanceFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mCounter++;
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, null);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String feedback = " Member counter: " + mCounter;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), feedback, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //member variables preserve its value after replace 
}
}
```

//NewInstanceFragment

```
public class NewInstanceFragment extends Fragment {

private int mCounter;

public static NewInstanceFragment getInstance() {
    return new NewInstanceFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mCounter++;
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, null);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String feedback = " Member counter: " + mCounter;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), feedback, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //member variables don’t preserve its value after replace 
}

}
```

//TestFragmentActivity

```
public class TestFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.test_fragments_activity);

    switchFragment();
    setListener();
}

private void setListener() {
    findViewById(R.id.tb_switch_fragment).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switchFragment();
        }
    });
}

private void switchFragment() {
    Fragment fragmentDisplayed = getCurrentFragmentDisplayed();
    Fragment fragmentToSwitch = null;
    if (fragmentDisplayed == null)
        fragmentToSwitch = SameInstanceFragment.getInstance();
    else if(fragmentDisplayed instanceof SameInstanceFragment)
        fragmentToSwitch = NewInstanceFragment.getInstance();
    else
        fragmentToSwitch = SameInstanceFragment.getInstance();
    setFragment(fragmentToSwitch);
}

private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public Fragment getCurrentFragmentDisplayed(){
    List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if(fragments == null) return null;
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        if(fragment.isVisible()) return fragment;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, create a member variable and a method to retrieve it, like this:

```
private DashboardFragment fragment;

private DashboardFragment getFragment() {
  if (fragment == null)
    fragment = new DashboardFragment();

  return fragment;
}
```

Then, when you want to access the fragment, instead of using `new DashboardFragment()`, use `getFragment()`.

Comment: Like @CarlosJimenez method better, as this will create a new fragment each time you change orientation. The two methods could be combined though, calling the getXFragment() recreating the fragment from tag and store in field in onCreate for instance.